# running mongoBD on apache2 with php8.0.03 on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: php, mongodb, apache

I managed to install mongoDB with php8.0 on an apache2 server but I'm unable to it.`<?php phpinfo(); ?>` shows me that mongoDB 1.9.1 is enabled and everything should be working but when I use `$mongo = new MongoDB\Driver\Manager("mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017");` I'll get the following error: `PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method MongoDB\\Driver\\Manager::selectDB() in / var/www/html/index.php:10\nStack trace:\n#0 {main}\n  thrown in /var/www/html/index.php`I don't know if it's the problem but it adds to all `\` another `\\`.

I am using [this](https://docs.mongodb.com/drivers/php/) tutorial to install mongoDB on my apache2 server with php.

My code: `$mongo = new MongoDB\Driver\Manager("mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017");`

When I try: `$mongo = new MongoDB\Client("mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017");`

I'll get pretty much the same error: `PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class "MongoDB\\Client" not found in /var/www/html/index.php:9\nStack trace:\n#0 {main}\n  thrown in /var/www/html/index.php on line 9`

Any idea how I can fix the issue? thanks!

Comment: Please share more details, like the code involved. According to https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.mongodb-driver-manager.php, the `Manager` class does not have such a method, so it's pretty likely that such code fails

Comment: [This library](https://github.com/alcaeus/mongo-php-adapter) has such a method, I'm wondering if that's what they are using.

Comment: I am using [this](https://docs.mongodb.com/drivers/php/) tutorial to install mongoDB on my apache2 server with php. I made sure that I installed it for the correct php version.

Comment: Please share more details, like the code involved. Where are you calling `selectDB()` in your code?

Answer (score -1):

Never mind I'm too stupid to read my own log. I thought the problem was cause by the provided code but `MongoDB\Driver\Manager`and it just jumped to the next error.